# Debian RAID drive size smaller than should be

Tags: debian, raid, raspberry-pi, software-raid, raspbian

#### Background

So I am new to setting up a RAID, so bear with me. I have tried to set up a RAID 10 with 4 hard drives. I am using `mdadm` to achieve this. I have successfully made my raid as `/dev/md0`. I should have around 2.5 terabytes of capacity for my drives. When I type:

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

It returns:

```
array size = 2441634816 (2328.52 GiB 2500.23 GB)
```

which 2500 GB is about 2.5 TB so seems fine. I am hosting the raid over samba and when I view the available space from another machine, it only shows about 16 GB or so:

#### Problem

My problem of course is that a good amount of my space isn't available. How do I get my full array to be available?

#### What I have tried

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/md0
```

Which is supposed to resize `md0` to use all space available..

The output of this is "The filesystem is already 610408704 blocks long. Nothing to do!"

The other command I saw to try is

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max
```

Which outputs "component size of `/dev/md0` unchanged at 0K" and when I check the size it is still the same.

Does anyone have any ideas for me to try?

Comment: What makes you think that the space is not available? output of `df`? 610408704 blocks seems right, if it's 4k blocks (610408704*4096/1024^3=2328.52GiB)

Comment: Well I was copying files to my new raid, from another computer and when I get to about 16GB it says the disk is full. Could something else be causing that?

Comment: Oh "I am hosting the raid over samba and when I view the available space from another machine". So are you sure the samba share is properly configured? Have you check with `df` locally?

Comment: Checking with df on the machine that hosts the raid doesn't display /dev/md0 at all

Comment: Is it not mounted? `findmnt /dev/md0` Make sure it's mounted to the path you set for the share.

Comment: Yep I mounted it to mnt/raid10. mnt/raid10 is actually what I publish with samba. Since I can read / write, that shows that it is at least mounted and has proper access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35607/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-eric-f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because md0 is not mounted, or the path of the share is not set to its mountpoint.

For the latter case, it's obvious that you should check your smb.conf.

For the former case, you can first check with `findmnt /dev/md0` or `mount | grep /dev/md0`.

Being able to read/write on its expected mountpoint (e.g. /mnt/raid0) does not necessarily means it is mounted. You are probably just accessing the root filesystem (16GB space, looks like the SD on your Pi).

In fact you can even just check the output of `df`. If /dev/md0 is not listed, it basically confirmed that it's not mounted too. If it's listed, you can check its usage locally. :D

Not being mounted can be due to the fact that there is no entry written for it in /etc/fstab, or it's not even assembled on boot.

Comment: The problem was definitely mdadm not assembling the drives and then not mounting them on boot. I had many problems getting mdadm.conf to do anything in terms of auto assembling. I did load the paths in there like many sites recommend but it would never assemble once rebooted. My final solution was to add the lines mdadm --assemble --scan and mount /mnt/raid10 /dev/md0 to my boot up script which now works perfectly fine. :)